# Unable to load even when the indentation is right

Tags: flutter

it's giving the error that unable to load asset

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        backgroundColor: Colors.teal,
        body: SafeArea(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              CircleAvatar(
                radius: 50.0,
                backgroundImage: AssetImage("images/rishi.jpg"),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

it's giving me error even when I checked the indentation of pubspec file... attaching below

```
flutter:

 
  uses-material-design: true

  
  assets:
    - images/rishi.jpg
```

Comment: Try `Image.asset('path')` to load. Also make sure the image asset is place in respective `path`

Comment: @Dinesh I forgot to cold start after attaching the source and was doing hot reload every time. Thanks though

Answer (score 0):

After attaching a new resource as an asset, it needs to have a cold start before hot reload. Otherwise, it's gonna give an error.